# rvest: how to scrape a list of links that shows only after dropdown selection

Tags: r, selenium, phantomjs, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape Public Health satistics data from 
https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/APP-JGP/KatalogJGP.aspx

The page shows two dependent dropdown lists. The source shows only the data for the top dropdown, the next will be filled dynamically with data (asp) only after i choose in the first dropdown. And only after I make the selection with both, I will see the list of links I would like to scrape.

My semiautomatic solution:to chose in both dropdowns, save the page and then scrape the list of links offline.
My current code shows that I understand how to get data from  comboboxes and from page once the selections are made:

```
#https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/app-jgp/
#From combo boxes I choose Year 2015 kat Ia and 
#A group of procedures, eg. A1- xxxxxx
#Then I save the page locally to C:/myPage/


library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_id <-
  function (x, myString) {
    require(stringr)
    str_extract(x, paste0("(?i)(?<=", myString, "\\D)\\d+"))
  }

# url <- "https://prog.nfz.gov.pl/APP-JGP/KatalogJGP.aspx"
url <- "C:/myPage/Narodowy Fundusz Zdrowia.htm"

pg <- read_html(url)

# The code below gets me the list from the first combo-box
# ContentPlaceHolder2_ddlSymylacjaJGP

n_values <-
  html_nodes(pg, "#ContentPlaceHolder2_ddlSymylacjaJGP option") %>% 
  html_attr("value")

n_descr <-
  html_nodes(pg, "#ContentPlaceHolder2_ddlSymylacjaJGP option") %>% 
  html_text() 

selCatYear <- tibble(n_values,n_descr)

# The code below gets me the list from the second combo-box
#ContentPlaceHolder2_ddlKatalogJGP

n_values <-
  html_nodes(pg, "#ContentPlaceHolder2_ddlKatalogJGP option") %>% 
  html_attr("value")

n_descr <-
  html_nodes(pg, "#ContentPlaceHolder2_ddlKatalogJGP option") %>% 
  html_text() 

setCatJGP <- tibble(n_values,n_descr)

# The code below gets me the list of urls I want.
# ContentPlaceHolder2_blKatalogJGP
n_values <-
  html_nodes(pg, "#ContentPlaceHolder2_blKatalogJGP li a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
n_descr <-
  html_nodes(pg, "#ContentPlaceHolder2_blKatalogJGP li a") %>% 
  html_text() 
setSingleJGP <- tibble(n_values,n_descr)
```

Question: **How can I automate selecting in the combo-boxes (dependent, content created dynamically) so that I get the lists of links? Is it possible just with rvest and R?** or other tool is needed (I have heard of Selenium but never used it).

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this other than with `RSelenium`.  It is quirky to use but straightforward once you get used to it.  Here is an answer I gave to a similar question a couple of weeks ago that will help you get started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307090/how-to-select-dropdown-box-using-rselenium/43307980#43307980